# Windows Phone Emulator / Hyper-V

Tags: windows-phone, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

When I try to run the Windows Phone Emulator for debugging purposes, I'm facing an error :

**"The virtual machine could not be started because the hypervisor is not running"**

I don't understand what's wrong. I enabled Hyper-V in Windows Features and in my BIOS. I checked the Hyper-V service and it is running. I also tried to disable all VMWare services to avoid a potential conflict but there's still the same error. I restarted and turned off then on my computer.

My hardware config is pretty good (i7, 8Gb...). My PC is running Windows 8.1 pro x64. VMWare machine virtualization works well too.

The problem appears when I try to launch the WP emulator from Visual Studio or from the Windows Hyper-V Manager.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

VMWare and HyperV can't coexist, and just disabling VMware services doesn't help.

One workaround - you can setup 2 boot entries, one with the hypervisor (for HyperV), another one without the hypervisor (for VmWare), and select the option you need just before Windows starts up.

[Here's an article](http://hyper-vandvmware.blogspot.com/2012/10/runing-both-hyper-v-and-vm-ware.html) explaining how to create that second boot option using command-line bcdedit.exe. Most likely, it was the VMware installer who disabled the hypervisor for your system, so the HyperV virtualization doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, making two boot options using bcdedit.exe works but I solved the problem by updating Windows... I don't know why but after completing Windows updates everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer here: [Windows Phone Emulator error, Hyper-V components not running, Windows 8.1 hosted in Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794062/windows-phone-emulator-error-hyper-v-components-not-running-windows-8-1-hosted?rq=1)

*I had the same issue with Visual Studio running on windows 8.1 in vmware player What I had to do to solve the problem was this :
Tick the box "Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI" in the processor settings of your VM
Add the line "hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = FALSE" in the file "Windows 8 x64.vmx" (add it between line 5 and 6. Not sure this matters, but at this line I'm sure it works)
Should be working fine*

It's amazing. It works and it saved me a lot of time. Kudos to the Florian C.