# Windows Phone Emulator error, Hyper-V components not running, Windows 8.1 hosted in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

Environment:

```
Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64-bit hosted in Windows Azure
Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 (Update 2)
```

I get the following error when trying to run a very simple phone app. I know MS says a VM-within-a-VM environment isn't supported, but I know it can work. Has anyone had success with this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Windows Phone Emulator

The Windows Phone Emulator wasn't able to ensure the virtual machine was running:

Something happened while starting a virtual machine: 'Emulator WVGA 512 MB.' failed to start.
(Virtual machine ID CADD6546-129A-4683-9A2D-52EAE777E888)

The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'Emulator WVGA 512 MB.'
because one of the Hyper-V components is not running
(Virtual machine ID CADD6546-129A-4683-9A2D-52EAE777E888).
```

Prior to seeing the error, the emulator emits the on-screen messages:

```
Loading ... 

The Windows Phone OS is starting ...
```

And then the error. Of all the Hyper-V services available, the Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service is the only one which is running.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Azure will enable nested virtualization (and hyperthreading) in [Dv3 and Ev3 VMs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/price-reductions-on-l-series-and-announcing-next-generation-hyper-threaded-virtual-machines/). Once released, using these VMs should allow you to run the Windows Phone Emulator without a problem. Corey Sanders has a quick [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Tuesdays-With-Corey/Tuesdays-with-Corey-M-Series-and-Nested-Virtualization-on-Azure) showing a demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[You cannot host it in Azure.  It needs to be a physical machine](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/14e8ef8d-dc87-4b9d-b41f-d7bf61ea3243/windows-phone-emulator-error-hyperv-components-not-running-windows-81-hosted-in-vmware-player?forum=wpdevelop)." -- Jeff Sanders (MSFT)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue with Visual Studio running on windows 8.1 in vmware player
What I had to do to solve the problem was this :

Tick the box "Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI" in the processor settings of your VM

Add the line "hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = FALSE" in the file "Windows 8 x64.vmx" (add it between line 5 and 6. Not sure this matters, but at this line I'm sure it works)

Should be working fine

Comment: Didn't work for me (admittedly on windows 10 on vmware), if I modify the vmx file, I get the 'Check the computer's BIOS' error :(

Comment: Doh! Have to select Hyper-V as the OS (in vmware->Manage->Settings->Options when VM is powered down): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBPPkhkSHRU (note: I haven't tried this in W10, I dropped back down to W8.1)

Answer (score 1):

Florian.C's answer got me on the right track to get the emulator working correctly in VMware Fusion on my MacBook Pro.  In Fusion, the settings are under the "Processors & Memory" section.  You have to open the "Advanced" section at the bottom and check the "Enable hypervisor applications for this virtual machine".  Once that was done, I had to also open the .vmx file and add the "hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"" line.  Originally I copied and pasted from SO and the VM threw an error when I booted it.  It turns out the " I added around FALSE were not normal quotes.  Once I fixed that, the VM booted and the emulator ran just fine under Fusion.  Thanks for the great info!